# c# multi-threaded logging - no locking

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have created a Logging utility class for my multithreaded C# app.  In order to ensure safe access to the file by all threads, I am locking on a static object as follows:

```
    private static readonly object locker = new object();

    public static void WriteLog(String message, params Object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = m_baseDir + GetFilenameYYYMMDD("_LOG", ".log");
            lock (locker)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
                String msg = String.Format(message, args);
                sw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -" + msg);
                sw.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
    }
```

However, when my application runs, I am still getting a `System.IO.Exception` on the line that initialises the `sw` variable.

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyApp\bin\Debug\Logs\MyApp_2017_09_18_LOG.log' because it is being used by another process.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

I do get messages in the Log though, so *some* thread(s) must be able to write to the file.

How can I fix this so all threads can access the file?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a using statement so that resources are released.

Comment: Just do yourself a favour ... https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file

Comment: The fiirst thing i would suspect is the StreamWriter itselfe.
Try disposing it (better using it inside a "using" statement)

Comment: I'd suggest you change your design to have a single writer thread and queue things to be written to the log

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem like before:

I just use this:

```
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
```

After the execution has done.

You can try this `sw.Dispose();` also.

Hope it helps: